# Finding the roots of the derivative of a trig function

Tags: calculus, roots

I have a function of which i need to find the maximum of. The function is :
D(t)= 12.17- 1.15cos(2*pi*t/365) + .18 sin(2*pi*t/365)
Taking the derivative with respect to t, I correctly get:

D'(t) = 2*pi/365 (1.15sin(2*pi*t/365) + .18cos(2*pi*t/365))
To find the maximum I set equal to zero to find critical points and solve for t:
t=arctan(-.18/1.15)*(365/(2*pi))

This results in t = -9.0194

The original function takes in days as values for t so this answer does not make sense. I am able to find the maximum through graphing on my ti calculator and finding the maximum over an interval for t between 0 and 365. the correct answer should be 173.48 for t but I cannot seem to get the answer analytically.

I believe my problem is in solving for t. Trig functions have never been my strong suit. Thanks for any help or advice you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of your function is periodic and have many many many zero's(because of the period which is ???). For positive values of $t$, you have roots close to 173, 356, 538, 721 that is to say (173 + 365 n /2), $n$ being any possible integer. I suggest you plot the derivative of you function as a function of $t$ from $0$ to $3650$.

Please notice that **-9.019 + 365/ 2 = 173.481**